# PHP Parse error on WP-CLI, not on web server

Tags: php, linux, wp-cli

I have a network of over a hundred sites and I try to use wp-cli to make bulk changes to many of these. Particularly to their wp_x_options table via wp --url=site.url option update

However, wp commands fail with several of my files, severely limiting the usefulness of the tool, particularly when trying to run with a list of urls | xargs wp --url={} ... because after the first failure, the rest are skipped.

The error I get is always the same:

```
PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in ... /functions.php
```

This error does not happen when loading the pages normally via the browser. My functions.php files are perfectly OK. Some of them don't have a closing ?> tag but that can't be the problem since many of these (lacking closing ?>) run OK with wp-cli.

Any thoughts?

WP-CLI 0.18.0
Wordpress 4.0.1
PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.4 (cli)
php.ini has 
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT
display_errors = Off

Comment: Also posted at https://github.com/wp-cli/wp-cli/issues/1754

Comment: It's hard to help diagnose this without seeing an example of a failing file.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in https://github.com/wp-cli/wp-cli/issues/1754#issuecomment-91361340, I figured this one out. It turns out it wasn't wp-cli's fault at all.

My confusion arose from the fact that I'm running a web server with nginx and php fpm, which has it's own php.ini . wp commands run php (cli) directly on the host and so the config can be different. In this case my php cli didn't allow short_open_tag (

Solution

Just enabled

```
short_open_tag=On
```

in /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
p.s. this is an aws ubuntu box

Comment: You would be better off to find the files in your system using short PHP tags and change them to not do that. Disabling short_open_tag everywhere is recommended for clarity. Short tags are bad practice due to portability, and additionally they don't adhere to the PHP basic coding standard PSR-1.

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware but it's not obvious how to do that in thousands of files reliably without having to supervise the whole process, which is not my role :)

Comment: Also the entire PHP version between webserver and cli can be different.